# Google Apps Script + React Web app error on button submit "Unsafe Javascript attempt...The Frame is attempting navigation of the top-level window"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-apps-script, iframe

I am using [this library (enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script)](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script) to build an apps script web app with React. I am using a button to process form data. When a user clicks submit, I run a function to process the data. I'm not actually POSTing the data anywhere, it stays in the app.

When using type="submit" on the button, I receive the following error:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://docs.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://localhost:3000/taxonomy-impl.html'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.`

At first I thought the page refresh behavior of a submit button is triggering this, so I tested a `event.preventDefault()` on the button, but that did not work.

`<Button type="submit" onSubmit={(event)=>{event.preventDefault()}}>Submit Form</Button>`

I have been able to workaround this by removing button type="submit" and running my function `onClick`, however I lose the automatic HTML5 form validation if I do that. Does anyone know how I can resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting `onSubmit` on the `<form>` tag instead of the button? I believe that should work

Comment: @AdityaR, yes that worked beautifully. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Answer in aditya's comment! Onsubmit should have been on the form rather than the button.